# How do I get an attribute of a function?

Tags: javascript, phaser

```
function randArray(arrayName) {
    arln = arrayName.length;
    arst = arrayName[Math.floor(Math.random() * arln)];
    return arst;

}


    create: function(){
        //starts physics engine
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        player = game.add.sprite(width/2, height/2, 'player');
        randSpawnItem = game.add.sprite(10, 10, randArray(randItem));
        randSpawnItem2 = game.add.sprite(50, 50, randArray(randItem));
```

So the randArray function works, and there is nothing wrong with the create. I'm using Phaser, and I'm trying to spawn items randomly (kind of like in Binding of Issac.) I forsee a problem in the future, when I'm detecting for collison, I need to know what item spawned to give the right kind of item to the player. How would I get that third attribute of `randSpawnItem` or `randSpawnItem2`, or is there another way to go at this completely? Sorry if that's a noobie question! Didn't know how to word it and didn't find it anywhere else. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: This question seems to be about programming in general, and as such is off topic for this site. A better place to find an answer would be a javascript tutorial.

Comment: @Peter [the site's policy on programming questions is continuing to evolve](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2294/39518) as we figure out how to best work together as a community. Myself, I think the problem described here - spawning a random item on a map and recording not just that object's visual but also what type of item was spawned in a way that's convenient to refer to for collision checking - that sounds like something a game programmer might have better & more complete/game-suitable suggestions for than we'd expect to get from a more general programmer.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can. Just change what's returned and how you interact with it.

```js
function randArray(arrayName) {
    arln = arrayName.length;
    arst = arrayName[Math.floor(Math.random() * arln)];
    return this;
}

var someArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var random = randArray(someArray);
document.getElementById('placeholder').textContent = 'Length: ' + random.arln + ' Random item: ' + random.arst;
```

```html
<div id="placeholder">
</div>
```

However, if you're going to continue using Phaser you might want to look at [how to extend sprites in Phaser](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/extending-sprite-demo-1). Creating custom objects will allow you to do most of the plumbing in a single location, and help with maintainability.